# I do run my code, and its suddenly gone, and I get this error, what should I do?, and how can I pick the right size for my background image?

Tags: python, image, pygame, resize, background-image

I do run my code, but its suddenly gone, and I get this error saying "screen.fill(background_img)TypeError: invalid color argument"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/146CG.png).
I dont also know how to resize the background image that i want to use for my screen background

```
pygame.init()
background_img = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Pictures\\maxresdefault.jpg")
(width, height) = (800, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hop Along')
screen.fill(background_img)

pygame.display.update()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace!

Comment: It is not suddenly gone. It is "gone" because you changes the code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) the display with an image. You must [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) an image:

<s>`screen.fill(background_img)`</s>

```py
screen.blit(background_img, (0, 0))
```

If the background image is a different size than the window, you can use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) to scale the image:

```py
background_img = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Pictures\\maxresdefault.jpg")
scaled_background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background_img, (width, height))
```

```py
screen.blit(scaled_background, (0, 0))
```